# What is the output cross-validated model (aka estimator) in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I have written a code in python using scikit-learn module to perform SVM classification with recursive feature elimination and cross-validation:

```
svc = SVC(kernel="linear") 
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y_train, 2), scoring='f1') 
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Unfortunately, I can not understand why the output classification when using cross-validated model (rfecv.fit) differs from the default model (svc.fit). Does the cross-validated model represent the best performing model based on the value of the prediction score (f1)? If yes, how to extract information on which data this model was trained and validated?

In addition, could anyone please explain why (according to scikit-learn documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) we need to held out a test set for final evaluation, even though we used cross-validation (seems like a waste of data to me)? As far as I know this final evaluation is called a holdout method, and is the simplest kind of cross validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models are doing different things. SVC trains the model on your full feature space, and makes predictions also on the full feature space. RFECV uses the full feature space and tunes the number of selected features. The final model, and any predictions it makes are based on a subset of your features (the ones that aren't eliminated).

You can inspect the RFECV object to get more information on what features were selected, or how various feature subsets performed (see [RFECV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html), .support_, .grid_scores_ and .ranking_ are all particularly relevant, as is [This example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html)).

The second part of your question is about data partitioning. Generally you should partition your data into three sets when building a new model:

- Training data is for training the model (obviously)
- Validation data is for tweaking the model (not for testing the model)
- Test data is for actually testing the model

The distinction between validation and test can be a bit fuzzy, but is very important. Taking your example (and assuming for the moment that you weren't using cross-validation), you would train your data on the training set. Now that it's working you might inspect the model and make some predictions using the validation set. This would give you some insight about which features were working, which features were not and the other *fiddly bits* about the model (e.g. what kind of kernel to use and any parameters on that kernel). You eventually decide to use some subset of your original features, and a polynomial kernel of degree 3.

Great! Now you have a working model. How well does that model actually do on unseen data? If you don't have a test set, you'll never know. All you know is how well you could get it to work on the validation set.

Now in your actual example RFECV uses cross-validation to do feature selection, which is an alternative way of handling the training-validation separation, which squeezes more out of your data (and is especially useful if you have a small number of samples and getting more is expensive/impossible).

Generally cross-validation is handled in averages (e.g. average performance over random k-folds), with the goal of the exercise being to keep tweaking the model until you're happy with the average performance. Only then do you test it (on the test set).

Edit: Fixed a link

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regarding my first question, does RFECV recursively remove attributes and build a model on those attributes that remain for each random cross-validation k-fold sets (i.e. random training and validation sets) and the final model is based on the k-fold sets with the minimum features required to produce high accuracy (e.g. f1)? Regarding my second question, in my case I'm not using validation data to tweak 'hyperparmeters' (e.g. kernel size, C and gamma), so why I can't treat it as test data?

Comment: Right. RFECV uses cross-validation to optimize the feature sets for you (rather than you doing it manually), where optimal is defined by whatever you pass to scoring (in your case f1, other options are [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) ).

Comment: For the test set, given that you're not messing with the model parameters and are using k-fold for validation, you only need two sets: Train/Validate and Test. Final evaluation should come from whatever you build based on the Train/Validate data (e.g. the RFECV model) applied to the unseen Test set.

If it's good, everything is awesome. If not, re-randomize and start over. Don't try to tweak things to make the model perform better on the Test set. Test is for final evaluation. Remember the goal isn't to do well on the test set, it's to do well on whatever happens afterwards.